# Error: "array index out of range" in multidimensional array

Tags: ios, swift

i have declared my array like

```
var tile = [[Int]]()
```

and after that i have initialize its value like

```
for (var index = 0; index < 4; index++)
    {
        for (var sindex = 0; sindex < 4; sindex++)
        {
        self.tile[index][sindex] = 0 // error here
            println("\(index) \(sindex)")

        }
    }
```

At run time it is giving an error "array index out of range"

Comment: Because tile is empty and you are asking for value at index which could go to 0..<4,

Comment: (That is a *runtime* error, not a compile time error.)

Comment: yes that is run  time @MartinR

Comment: @MartinR swift is very safe and can figure out this type of issue at compile time, so it will be a compile time error

Comment: @C_X: Try it: Compiling the code with "Project > Build" (cmd-B) succeeds. Running the code with "Project > Run" (cmd-R) throws the error.

Comment: @C_X i could not get you.  are you saying to specify the limit of array  or to initiate it ?

Comment: Agreed with Martin @C_X

Comment: @MartinR you are right my it will be a ru time error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the commentators @C_X & @MartinR say, your array is empty. Here's how to initialise it as you want...

```
var tile = [[Int]](count:4, repeatedValue: [Int](count: 4, repeatedValue: 0))

for index in 0 ..< 4 {
    for sindex in 0 ..< 4 {
        tile[index][sindex] = 0 // no error here now...
        print("\(index) \(sindex)")
    }
}
```

...of course, the `for` loops are now redundant, if you just want zeroes!

Comment: All this old syntax. You're writing Swift so write Swift... `for index in 0..<4`

Comment: I know. There seems to be a lot of "I know Javascript therefore I know swift" and no effort to actually learn the best practices of how to actually do things.

Comment: but i don't want to give them zero value at the time of declaring @Grimxn   so any other option

Comment: You're right. We need to set a good example! Changed the answer.

Comment: @hatim - what DO you want them to be at time of declaration? If you want them "undefined" make it an array of `Int?` and set them to `nil` in the declaration. If you don't know the size of the array use @Greg's other answer...

Comment: @hatim the option is either create the "default value" arrays and then populate them or build the arrays up before inserting them in the main 2D array (like Greg's answer does).

Answer (score 3):

As per comments you know that you are asking for value at index in an empty array. If you want to initialise the array you should try something like this:

```
for (var index = 0; index < 4; index++)
{
    tile.append([])
    for (var sindex = 0; sindex < 4; sindex++)
    {
        tile[index].append(sindex)

        print("\(index) \(sindex)")

    }
}
```

Comment: this was actually the way the go for me, since I'm getting an unknown sized json response which still needs to go through some checks.