# Fatal Error: Index out of range... Why wont this code compile?

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array, fatal-error, conways-game-of-life

I'm new at swift and trying to set up a 10x10 2D array of Bools where one out of three are true and the rest are false. For some reason this wont run, instead giving me a lengthy error with the reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

```
var before = [[Bool]]()

for x in 0..<10 {
for y in 0..<10 {
    if arc4random_uniform(3) == 1 {
        before[x][y] = true
    }
    else {
        before[x][y] = false
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your array is empty. There's nothing at index `x`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: "array index out of range" in multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650268/error-array-index-out-of-range-in-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Did the answers below answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting **fatal error: Index out of range** because you can't index into an empty array in Swift (because even array index `0` doesn't exist yet).

One solution is to initialize your two dimensional array by using nested array initializers.  If you initialize it to all `false`, you then only have to set the `true` values:

```
var before = [[Bool]](count: 10, repeatedValue: [Bool](count: 10, repeatedValue: false))

for x in 0..<10 {
    for y in 0..<10 {
        if arc4random_uniform(3) == 1 {
            before[x][y] = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It Looks like you are initialising your 'before' object as an array, but then assigning to it as a dictionary.  ( also how you are assigning it looks like it could do with a tweak.

[Bool] = Array of Bools
[[Bool]] = Array of Array of Bools

to assign to above you need to create a [Bool] Array with your result, and append it to the object above.

Since it seems that you want to use before as a Dictionary, then you can just change your initialiser to be :

```
var before = [Int:[Int:Bool]]()
```

and change your function to be:

```
for x in 0..<10 {
    for y in 0..<10 {
        let test = x
        if arc4random_uniform(3) == 1 {
            before[x] = [y:true]
        }
        else {
            before[x] = [y:false]
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will successfully be able to call the values using

```
//To call before[1][3]
if let before = before[1] {
   print(before[3])
}
```

If I am wrong and you want it to work as an Array of Array of Bools, then you need to change how you add your results to the 'before' array to:

1. Firstly Generate the "X value " Array of Bools
2. Append this Bool Array to the 'before' Array

> `var before = [[Bool]]()`

```
for x in 0..<10 {
    var yArray = [Bool]()
    for y in 0..<10 {
        if arc4random_uniform(3) == 1 {
           yArray.append(true) // Array of Bools
        }
        else {
            yArray.append(false)
        }
    }
    before.append(yArray)

}
//To call before[1][3]
print(before[1][3])
```