# Swift array index out of range

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, swift2

Why this is not working?

```
var lottoTaulukko = [Int]()
var finalLottoTaulukko = [[Int]]()

var laskuri1 = 0
var laskuri2 = 0

while laskuri2 < Int(riviLaskuri) {

    while laskuri1 < Int(lottoMuoto) {
        showRowsLabel.stringValue += "\(lottoTaulukko[laskuri1])"
        finalLottoTaulukko[laskuri2][laskuri1] = lottoTaulukko[laskuri1] // ERROR IS HERE IN THIS LINE! fatal error: Index out of range

showRowsLabel.stringValue += " "
        laskuri1 += 1
    }

    laskuri1 = 1
    showRowsLabel.stringValue += "\n"
    if laskuri2==10 {showRowsLabel.stringValue += "\n"}
    lottoTaulukko.shuffle()
    laskuri2 += 1
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: "array index out of range" in multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650268/error-array-index-out-of-range-in-multidimensional-array)

Comment: You are trying to access an element of the array by index, but the index you passed is out of the range of the array. Looking at your code I think that the finalLottoTaulukko that you are trying to index out of its range. Have you initialised this array? What's its size?

Comment: It seems that both of your arrays are empty when you try to access their contents.

Comment: Pleast think about restructuring your code. Processing data and modifying UI components should be two seperated parts of your application logic or should at least be seperated into two different, subsequently called methods. Do not process data and modify your label in one place as you do currently.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the arrays size likewise:

```
let size = ARRAY.count
```

And check out if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if your index exists:

```
while laskuri1 < Int(lottoMuoto) {
    if let lt = lottoTaulukko[laskuri1]?{
        showRowsLabel.stringValue += "\(lottoTaulukko[laskuri1])"
        if finalLottoTaulukko[laskuri2]? != nil && finalLottoTaulukko[laskuri2][laskuri1]? != nil{
            finalLottoTaulukko[laskuri2][laskuri1] = lottoTaulukko[laskuri1] 
        }
    }

showRowsLabel.stringValue += " "
        laskuri1 += 1
}
```